# Remove fonts but default theme is still loading them

Tags: rwd-theme, scss, font-family

I am customizing rwd theme, i have removed `railway font` from the theme using `local.xml` file and i have verified it checking `inspect element in browser` below is my `local.xml` code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Local.xml
Local Layout Modifications For Our Local Theme
-->
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/font-awesome.min.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

And then i am loading google fonts in my `scss file`. Below is my code

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600|Allerta);

$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
$red: #d22629;
$orange: #f57f20;
$gray: #f2f3f5;
$opensans: 'Open Sans';
$allerta: 'Allerta';

body {background:$gray; font-family:$opensans !important;}
```

But still it is loading the default railway font. I don't understand where it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers doesn't support some fonts.And instead of using google links, You just give this a try.

1.Download the font family you want.

2.Create a folder named 'fonts' inside skin/frontend/package/theme/css/
(I used only css to style my site. so I created inside css folder.If it didnt work try creating it under scss folder)

3.Copy the font files which you have downloaded into the folder you created.

4.Then in your stylesheet call the font like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MuliRegular';
src: url('fonts/muli-regular.eot');
src: url('fonts/muli-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/muli-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/muli-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/muli-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/muli-regular.svg#MuliRegular') format('svg');
      }
```

In my case It was 'Muliregular'. You should specify the font you want.